# How to get view/trigger before altered on PL-SQL?

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, database-administration, sql-view

I have a view: 
 
Yesterday | myview  | `select * from mat where bereich='AAA'` |
Today    | myview  | `select * from mat where bereich='BBB' AND typ='BR'` |

---

someone has altered my view on prod or I forgot to back up the previous query and it has been committed

How to get my query/myview yesterday back ?

Thanks.

Comment: hmmmm, it seems like your system is running without source control for schema scripts or restricted/monitored access to production. Bad practice all round. I know this doesn't help you right now, but this is an important learning point. Applications which don't treat their production database with the appropriate level of respect are inevitably doomed.

Comment: You allright my system is running without source control, this will be shared with colleagues to discuss about best practice. thanks mate for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `user_views` data dictionary view to see former `text` of your view. For this aim, you need some privileges such as

```
SQL> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> grant flashback on user_views to myschema;
```

and minimum requirements for using flashback techniques such as

```
SQL> select p.value 
  from v$parameter p
 where p.name = 'db_flashback_retention_target';

 VALUE
 -----
  1440 -- should be set to 1440(minute) as minimum to get the value for the day before.
```

provided by your *DBA*.

Then, connect to your schema

```
SQL> conn myschema/mypwd
```

and use the following query

```
SQL> select t.text 
  from user_views 
  as of timestamp systimestamp - interval '1' day t
where t.view_name = 'MYVIEW';
```

to get the `text` of your view in the past to recreate.

*P.S.* the keyword `day` might be replaced with `hour`, `minute` or `second` due to your need or wish.

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a *stored query*, nothing happened to data. Just recreate the view using the old query:

```
create or replace myview as
  select * 
  from mat
  where bereich = 'AAA';
```

Comment: I do not know the old query because someone has altered the view. it is nothing happened to the data ,but my user shouted with their data that does not appear , I mean is there any way to rollback the view?

Comment: You have a copy of your query in your source code control repository, right?